# How to convert a list to a string in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a list `L =[a+b,b+c]` and I want to convert it to a string and print the output `a+bb+c`.

Can you please help me convert this list to a string? I tried using `atomic_list_concat` in SWI-Prolog but it gave a type error for `a+b`.

Comment: Chances are: you actually want a better representation instead.

Answer (score 3):

In SWI-Prolog:

```
?- with_output_to(atom(Atom), maplist(write, [a+b, b+c])).
Atom = 'a+bb+c'.
```

You can replace `write` with a call to a custom predicate if you need more control over how your terms (e.g. `a+b`) are written.

Answer (score 1):

The members of your list are compound terms, so you have to make them atomic before calling `atomic_list_concat`:

```
custom_print(L) :-
  maplist(term_to_atom, L, L1),
  atomic_list_concat(L1, L2),
  print(L2).
```