# SWI Prolog, array of arrays to array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, prolog

I have function that gives me array

```
S = [
      publication(12, stout, call),
      publication(19, jones, wendalissa),
      publication(26, olson, dessert),
      publication(33, hansen, away)
    ]
```

and I want to change this array to another

```
S = [
      19-olson-wendalissa,
      7-author-away,
      22-jackson-book,
      33-anotherauthor-anotherbook
    ].
```

This doesn't help me [How to convert a list to a string in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419442/how-to-convert-a-list-to-a-string-in-prolog)

```
custom_print(L2) :-
  sol(S),
  S = [
        publication(12,A1,B1),
        publication(19,A2,B2),
        publication(26,A3,B3),
        publication(33,A4,B4)
      ],
  L = [
        [12,A1,B1],
        [12,A2,B2],
        [26,A3,B3],
        [33,A4,B4]
      ],
  maplist(term_to_atom, L, L1),
  atomic_list_concat(L1,'-',L2).
```

I'm noob in prolog, but I'm trying to understand this

Comment: The result should have the same elements as the first list or some should be ignored? In this second case, can you state what elements you don't want?

Comment: @damianodamiano The result should have the same elements, but not exactly in the order

Comment: What's the reason to do this conversion? Can use e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2 for formatting output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution

```
convert(publication(Id,A,B),Id-A-B).
convert_list(L,L1):-
    maplist(convert,L,L1).

?- convert_list([publication(12, stout, call), publication(19, jones, wendalissa), publication(26, olson, dessert), publication(33, hansen, away)], L).
L = [
12-stout-call,
19-jones-wendalissa,
26-olson-dessert,
33-hansen-away
]
```

Comment: What should i change to get this array in one move? To get my list S and to convert it 
?-convert_list(sol(S),L).
convert_list(S,L).

Comment: convert(publication(Id,A,B),Id-A-B).
convert_list(L):-
    sol(S),S = [publication(N1,A1,B1),publication(N2,A2,B2),
         publication(N3,A3,B3),publication(N4,A4,B4)],
    L = [[N1,A1,B1],[N2,A2,B2],[N3,A3,B3],[N4,A4,B4]],
    maplist(convert,S,L).

I'm trying this and then write ?-convert_list(L).
But it gives me false

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Note that in Prolog we have lists, not arrays

Comment: Sorry, but can I get this list with right output in one move? I don't want to put the whole array in convert_list function. Can I change something to write ?-convert_list(sol(S),L).

Comment: No because predicates in prolog do not have a return value. The computation must be stored in another argument

Comment: The [func](https://github.com/mndrix/func/) module on GitHub would let you rewrite that as `?- L = convert_list $ sol.` but behind the scenes it's rewriting the terms to do it the normal way with an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 0):

Given `sol/1`, something like this:

```
sol(S) :- S = [
      publication(12, stout, call),
      publication(19, jones, wendalissa),
      publication(26, olson, dessert),
      publication(33, hansen, away)
    ].
```

Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't seem like it should be more complex than this:

```
fetch_pubs(Qs) :- sol(Ps), convert_pubs(Ps,Qs).

convert_pubs( [] , [] ).
convert_pubs( [P|Ps], [Q|Qs]) :- convert_pub(P,Q), convert_pubs(Ps,Qs).

convert_pub( publication(A,B,C), A-B-C ).
```

Then it's a simple matter of

```
?- fetch_pubs(L).
```

which produces

```
L = [
      12-stout-call,
      19-jones-wendalissa,
      26-olson-dessert,
      33-hansen-away
]
```

If you want the terms in the final list to be atoms or strings, simply add (if you're using SWI Prolog, a `term_to_atom/2` or a `term_string/2` to `convert_pub/2`:

```
% convert the term A - B - C to an atom
convert_pub( publication(A,B,C), P ) :- term_to_atom(A-B-C,P).
```

Or

```
% convert the term A - B - C to a string
convert_pub( publication(A,B,C), P ) :- term_string(A-B-C,P0.
```

If you're using another Prolog, how you get from a term to an atom or string is likely implementation dependent.